# How pass files on I have used grep to sed with -n switch to substitute files

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have problem to understand how store files on I am grepping to modify with sed.

`grep -Fr "from 'app" --include=*.js src/ | sed  -s "s:from 'app: from ':"`

I have seen using grep with sed on one known file to store into variable.

`$file = file.txt`

`grep "import from {} redux" $file | sed -s "s/ReactJS/ReactJS./"` $file`

How to do for multiple files *.js in src?

Comment: Don't use any GNU grep options to recursively find files. Use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** within files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-l` option in `grep` to output matching filenames and then pipe ut to `xargs` to process each matching filename:

```
grep -ZlrF "from 'app" --include=*.js | xargs -0 sed "s:from 'app: from ':"
```

Used `-Z` option in `grep` to delimit output using NUL character that it can be consumed using `xargs -0`. This is used to take care of filenames with whitespaces and other special characters.

---

If you don't have `gnu grep` then use `find + sed` as suggested by Ed:

```
find . -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 sed "s:from 'app: from ':"
```

Comment: Yes but I need instead printing, sed -n. I have tried | sed -n "" `  ``xargs -0/`` `,
it won't work as sed on file because it didn't substitute at all